# On Github, see if a tag includes a pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Say I am looking at a pull request from `alice/foo` to `bob/foo`. `bob/foo` has a tag `v1.0` at `abc67`. From the website, how can I tell whether Alice's pull request is an ancestor of `v1.0`?

Comment: From Git itself it's easy. From the GitHub web site, I don't think it's even possible, but I'm no GitHub expert.

Comment: If you're PR'ing from `alice/foo-repo/foo-branch` onto `bob/foo-repo/foo-branch`, if the former is an ancestor of the latter, the PR will show up as empty (IIRC).

Comment: @Pockets Right. What I'm interested in is not the situation where the pull request is against v1.0, but where v1.0 is some later (in time) commit that may or may not descend from Alice's pull request. Basically I just ant a way to see if one commit is an ancestor of another without cloning; after cloning it would be simple.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. The network graph might have what you need (`https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/network`) but I don't know if it's guaranteed to work in all situations (e.g. tags that have diverged from `master`).

Comment: The feature exist on gitlab, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOiGI.png) (on commit detail view).

Answer (score 1):

Something I tried -- I don't know 100% if this works as I think it does, but in case it helps:

- I went to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tags
- I clicked on `ee2e377` under `3.1.1`, which took me to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/ee2e377494a882f043e6d8abc67ac6370ee83d9c
- I saw that its parent is `51c29dc` https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/51c29dc1fecc675054762fb1f50a0cdd6b1f0df0

So.. if somebody makes a pull request, I'm thinking that I should be able to go to the branch, check their git commit log from where they're making the pull request from, and check if the commits related to the tag exist there.

On https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/3.1.1, `ee2e37` and `51c29dc` both exist.

On https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commits/master, you'll see that `ee2e37` doesn't exist, but `51c29dc` does, which would have me thinking: "a pull request made from here to the `3.1.1` tag actually doesn't include all of the commits that come with the `3.1.1` tag".